# Understanding Passport.js - Tampering with the serializedUser

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

Am trying to wrap my head around **passport.js**, and am sure I am not using it correctly.

Particularly with the `serializeUser()` and `deserializeUser()` functions. My functions look similar to the two below. I am essentially pushing my database `user._id` into the session (which I don't like to do), and can view it easily in the browser with a cookie viewer.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  done(null, id);
});
```

So, for every secure request, I run an `isAuthenticated()` function which checks that the user is Authenticated with Passport, and then I use the deserialized ID in `req.user` to perform various CRUD operations on the database.

What I am wondering is what would stop an authenticated user from replacing their own user._id with someone else's user._id in the session, and gaining access to all these CRUD db operations for a different user.

- Does passport have some sort of hashing algorithm to check the serialized data hasn't been tampered with?
- Should I not be using the returned ID for my database CRUD operations?
- Is there another way to avoid sending the user._id to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is the session middleware which makes sure that session data is not tampered, you just need to provide the secret option which will be used to sign it.

From express session middleware documentation (https://github.com/expressjs/session)

secret - session cookie is signed with this secret to prevent tampering.

Ex. `app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))`

- According to the passport docs(http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/):

> The serialization and deserialization logic is supplied by the
>   application, allowing the application to choose an appropriate
>   database and/or object mapper, without imposition by the
>   authentication layer.

So, you have to implement serializeUser() and deserializeUser() methods. Serialize method will return the identity information to recover the user on future requests. And that identity information will be saved in the session. Deserialize method should be able to identify the user based on that identity information. Whether you use database id, some randomly generated string, UUID or something similar is up to you and your security requirements.